# How do I get a substring value from a Sql column of varbinary type?

Tags: xml, t-sql, types, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am trying to get a substring, `FIRST_NAME`, attribute value from `ADDRESS_XML` column in a table using a simple select query. The column type is `varbinary(1000)`.

`GetXml` is a custom method defined elsewhere which works fine.

My where clause is

```
dbo.GetXml(ADDRESS_XML).exist('xpathExpression') = 1
```

Following is one row of the ADDRESS_XML column:

```
<PostalAddress xmlns="http://tempuri.org/PostalAddress.xsd">
    <PostalAddress TITLE="Mr" FIRST_NAME="John" LAST_NAME="SMITH" 
                   ADDRESS="207a Stratford Road, Shirley" CITY="Solihull" 
                   COUNTY="West Midlands" POSTCODE="B90 3AH" 
                   COUNTRY="United Kingdom" CONTACT_INFO="" 
                   EMAIL_ADDRESS="" PHONENO="" />
    </PostalAddress>
```

What should XPath expression be ?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express
The varbinary column is storing a string as hex, which is why I am using a proprietory GetXml() method on it.

Comment: ***WHY*** are you storing perfectly valid XML in a `VARBINARY` column?!?!? Makes no sense at all..... if looks like XML, smells like XML, quacks like XML - it probably **IS** XML and should be treated as such and stored **as** `XML` .....

Comment: I'm at work - I have no control over the bad practices of our codebase :)

Comment: Your questions is not clear. You talk about XML stored as varbinary but you have a function that returns XML so that part is already taken care of right? You want an XPath expression to get the value of `FIRST_NAME` and your example query uses `exist` in a where clause that is tests for existence of nodes instead of returning values. You can not return a value in `exist`. You could compare the value of `FIRST_NAME` against a constant or a variable but it does not look like that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, great, so how do I compare the value of FIRST_NAME against a constant as that is all I want to do. Should I use substring() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sql:variable()` to use a variable in a predicate in the `exist` function.

```sql
declare @FirstName nvarchar(100) = 'John';

with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://tempuri.org/PostalAddress.xsd')
select *
from T
where dbo.GetXml(ADDRESS_XML).exist('/PostalAddress/PostalAddress[@FIRST_NAME = sql:variable("@FirstName")]') = 1;
```

Or against a constant value in the xPath

```sql
with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://tempuri.org/PostalAddress.xsd')
select *
from T
where dbo.GetXml(ADDRESS_XML).exist('/PostalAddress/PostalAddress[@FIRST_NAME = "John"]') = 1;
```

Comment: Neither of the above suggestions returned any result set, but neither did I get any errors either!

Comment: @dotNetBlackBelt Ok, really hard to tell what you did wrong there without some code that reproduces what you see. [Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/666e4/1) that proves it is indeed working as expected. You might just have missed some tiny detail like that XML is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked, here is the XPath expression to get `FIRST_NAME` attribute :

```
/PostalAddress/PostalAddress/@FIRST_NAME
```

or if you meant to get `<PostalAddress>` having `FIRST_NAME` attribute value equals `1` :

```
/PostalAddress/PostalAddress[@FIRST_NAME='1']
```

You may need to register default namespace first ([MSDN: Specifying Default Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx)). Though, I'm not sure how you intended to use the XPath exactly.